# Is there any way for me to find which questions/answers I have upvoted/downvoted?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page

The other day I was trying to find a question that I knew I had voted on. I remembered enough about it to search for it, and of course I could see once I got there that I had in fact voted on it, but I was wondering if there is any way to see all such questions. Like from my profile I can see what comments I've made, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At some point over the last nearly-five years, this got implemented in the form of the Votes tab on the user profile. It shows you the votes you cast and allows you to break them down by vote type:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There used to be a log of recent votes in a tab in the profile page, but it was removed several months ago because it was deemed useless.

But it's back now!

Comment: That's why I asked, because I remember seeing that but couldn't find it lately. It seems useful to me at least...

Comment: I just wanted to find a question I know I voted on recently and am missing this feature too.

Answer (score 1):

You can see which (non-community wiki) questions you have downvoted by going back through your user history (the little envelope icon) because it is recorded as -1 to your reputation.  I made use of this when I hit 2000 rep (and editing privileges) by finding and retracting downvotes on posts that had since been improved.

Comment: In my case I was looking for an upvote, and in general all votes, but this is good to know.

Comment: @jtolle et al: nowadays finding your downvotes is much easier: [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to see what you have voted on. The system tries its best to keep voting anonymous. Even in the data dump there is no way to see this information.

Comment: I switched acceptance to Anna Lear's new answer since things have changed since 2009