# Finding the questions / answers that I've voted on

Tags: feature-request, support, voting

I know I just voted on a question but I can't find it again.

Is there [still no way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/is-there-any-way-for-me-to-find-stackoverflow-questions-on-which-i-have-cast-vote/27739#27739) to see a list of questions and/or answers that I've **just** voted on?

<sub>disclaimer: I've seem the duplicate right before posting this. I was using my main form of finding related questions, which is "*asking a question*, typing the *title* and checking the *related questions*". But instead to go and post another question on ***"Should we post duplicates on purpose if they're sufficiently different?"***, I'll just go ahead and hope the other one is outdated.</sub>

Comment: Unless you browse SO in p-p-p-privacy mode, what about your browser history?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/is-there-any-way-for-me-to-find-stackoverflow-questions-on-which-i-have-cast-vote

Comment: @balpha it's not so good. It's messed thanks to my way-to-many-tabs complex. Plus I actually browse in privacy mode when I'm not at home. As of the "possible duplicate", please, pay more attention to the question. I've already linked that and explained why I posted it anyway.

Comment: So? "Yeah, officer, I know that stealing is illegal, but I put down a note saying 'I know stealing is wrong, I'm doing it anyway', how can you arrest me then?"

Comment: @balpha it's actually "but I'm just stealing wafles, mr officer!"

Comment: As a work around you can find those you've *down* voted (excluding community wiki I guess...) by visiting the `/reputation` page with the [audit helper script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/94727) and searching for `(-1)`. There's currently no work around for upvotes that I know of...

Comment: @DMA exactly 1 year later and on april fools! Anyways, I couldn't see what you meant - I thought reputation only shows votes you've *received* rather than *cast*. And I installed the audit helper script but still couldn't find where my single downvote went to, though I remember clearly where.

Comment: @Cawas - I came here from a cross-link on another [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71440/badge-suggestion-responsive-aka-quality-control-adaptability-etc/83280#83280) the community user had bumped. But, this *does* work! Here's a screenshot of my audit, looking at a random downvote of mine, both [without](http://i.imgur.com/mhX8B.png) and [with](http://i.imgur.com/HmJKD.png) the audit helper script. Make sure you're looking at the `/reputation` page - http://stackoverflow.com/reputation. And finally, remember they won't show up if the post is deleted.

Comment: @DMA wow, the screenshots helped me a lot realizing I was at the wrong page. And the whole link too. Of course I was going to *reputation tab*! Anyway, you should add this as an answer. Even if it's half the answer, it's great! Thanks :)

Comment: @Cawas FYI, you *can* also see downvotes on the reputation tab as well ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/WcRqj.png)) and it links without needing a userscript. ***But***, you have to open the days one-at-a-time, so it's a lot slower to search through...  And I'll post it up as an answer soonish...

Comment: @DMA so we need a userscript to collapse / expand all items there! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you find your up votes, but since down voting costs reputation, you can find those votes are still active (ie, not those on deleted posts) by looking at your reputation changes - this obviously only works for yourself, you cannot see this information for other users.

The **first option** is your reputation audit page (as in `http://stackoverflow.com/reputation` or which site you wish to check). Then, just use your browser to search for the text `(-1)`. You then you have the post ID you need, with which you can try and hunt it down manually, this requires effort, so I'd recommend using the [audit helper](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/94727) user script as well, which changes the post IDs in to links, saving you valuable time.

Here's an example, a shot of the first of my down votes that happens to still be active:

Without the script (the normal view):
[image: Reputation audit showing highlighted down-vote]

With the script (clickable links):
[image: Reputation audit with Audit Helper userscript showing highlighted down-vote]

The **second option** is to look at the reputation tab on your user profile as this displays downvotes as well:
[image: User profile r]

Unfortunately, you have to expand each individual day manually to search for the down votes, so this is probably quite a bit slower , but as an advantage the posts are linked for you without the need of a user script - and is probably very speedy if you want to find a post you just down voted.

As a final reminder, remember that **these methods will not find down votes against deleted posts**.

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but a perfect answer and highly acceptable! :)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>In the database, a vote's owner is not recorded. The only things recorded with the owner are answers, questions, comments, and revisions.</strike>

Wait, if you go to a question and look you'll see that you voted on the question. Why isn't it possible to see what votes we placed on what posts in a nice list? (of course, this should be private and not included in data dumps though)

Comment: Precisely my point. The info is on the database somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not that you voted on, other than just the counts. Just answered and questions.

Comment: Mind elaborating a little more on this, and maybe giving some references?

Comment: When you view your profile you can see the count of your up/down votes. You can also wee all questions you asked and any questions you answered. See http://stackoverflow.com/users/274502/cawas

Comment: Well, that's not what the question was about at all! Check the link I've gave there.