# Has my suggestion been forgotten?

Tags: support, meta, discussion

Some time ago, I made [a badge suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71440/badge-suggestion-responsive-aka-quality-control-adaptability-etc) here which seemed pretty popular; it got quite a few up-votes and comments, with people saying they liked it and making further suggestions to improve on it.

But what it didn't seem to get was much attention from the Powers That Be.

What do the Stack Exchange folks think of it, and are there any plans to implement it?

Note, I'm not precious about getting it implemented - if it's not considered useful enough or it's too hard to do, that's fine, or even if you've just made a note to come back to it later; I guess all I'm saying is I'd just like to know that it hasn't been ignored.

Comment: Maybe you should add a bounty on your suggestion to try to draw some more attention to it?

Comment: Just FYI, this is not a particularly productive or effective way to get it considered...

Comment: @Cody - hmyeah, I kinda agree with you. But that's not really what I was trying to do. I was more just trying to understand how things work. I know there is a tag for [status-planned], but I'd like to get a better idea of when that gets used? And perhaps for the time between that, there could be another one for [status-under-consideration]? Anyway, if I came across the wrong way, then I apologise. (also, Peter's edit seems to have changed the phrasing into more of a direct question than I originally intended it to be)

Answer (score 4):

It's currently #7 in the list of [top feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests). Whether or not that means it's been "forgotten", I don't know.

You can always give it a bounty to draw more attention to it.