# "Good update" badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge suggestion: Responsive (aka Quality Control, Adaptability, etc …)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71440/badge-suggestion-responsive-aka-quality-control-adaptability-etc)

When I add an answer this may not be a *good* answer, so an user downvote my anser. Then, I decide to update my answer and that same user, considering my update a *good* update, decides to upvote my answer.
This sequence of actions might be a good reason to earn a new badge?

Comment: +1... I can see an edit which turns a post with negative votes into a post with positive votes being a worthy badge... "Medic", "Resurrection", "Healer", "Good *recovery*"...?

Comment: As long as you have a one-time bronze badge in mind, agreed.