# How to check which questions I voted on?

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the questions / answers that I've voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/finding-the-questions-answers-that-ive-voted-on)

I'm using votes as a sort of alternative for favorites. The thing is that I haven't found how to see the question I voted on. In fact I'm not even sure that's possible, but I'd like to see a sort of recap with the questions I voted on, etc.

I found this :

```
Votes Cast
all time        by type     month       week        day
```

but that doesn't give me any detail. Is there a way to consult it?

Comment: I think I've answered this question before [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/finding-the-questions-answers-that-ive-voted-on/85677#85677). In short: you can't, but you can hackishly find the *answers* you've downvoted (since question downvotes are free you can't see them).

Comment: That's not the purpose of votes. You should vote a post because you think it's good or bad, not because you want to track it later. So it's not big deal the system won't help you misuse it. What's wrong with the favorites mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would anyone wants to do this? (And its not possible, besides finding the -1 for a answer downvote in the reputation list)

You do have at the moment 660 upvotes on SO. I appreciate that, you have 40 upvotes a day no need to spare some, the next day you will get 40 new votes (and those left from the day before are gone).

These are so many votes, this would be such a long list, why would you like to find them again?

If you like a question/answer for some reason or want to review it later on, then favorite it, they are easy to find (when there are not hundreds of them) on your favorite tag on your user page.

Comment: tracking the votes could give the possibility to get 2 different lists. With Gmail (sorry for copyright stuff) u got "starred" and "important" messages. This only gives you a more flexible way to organize the posts u liked but its impossible Ill figure another way, I was just asking. Thats why I was asking !

Comment: I don't know that gmail feature, but I assume the usage of votes here is (should be) different. I voted more than 2500 times. When I see an answer that is correct and has a good explanation, then it gets my upvote, this is often stuff I already know, (because of that I am able to say its "good"), the amount of votes on a post is to show other users how "useful" this post is. But normally there is no need for me to see this post again. If I want to see it again, I favorite it.

Comment: I don't think it's _impossible_ to do. A [rep recalc](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) shows a list of all the votes you received with an id that probably refers to the up-/downvoted post. That seems pretty close already.

Comment: @Aberrant thats not about votes on the OPs post, its about votes the OP did, they do not show up in the rep list, because they don't produce rep.

Comment: @sterma: They do produce rep for others though, so they're somewhere in the database as unique instances. It also remembers who cast them (you see a highlighted arrow next to the posts) so the necessary data appears to available. It might be very complicated, but it doesn't seem impossible to display it on the (private) profiles somehow.

Comment: Waaait, I somehow interpreted this question as a feature request, my bad!