# Can the Votes Cast link point to something useful to me (the user)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, activity-dropdown

Clicking on the `votes cast` link in the activity dropdown currently takes us to the list of [top voters](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters).

[image: the votes cast link in the activity dropdown]

Couldn't this be a more useful, personal link?  Everything else in the dropdown are about me (the user).

Make it point to a page that lists all the votes I (the user) have casted.  As far as I know, it's not possible to even find what questions or answers you've actually voted on (if you were interested in finding them).  The only exception is answer downvotes which will show up in the reputation pages.  I'd like to be able to revisit the posts that I had voted on.

Now that the votes tab has been included in our profiles ([Show recently cast downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130383)), could this link be updated to point to the tab now?

Comment: Used to be such a page. Hardly anyone used it. Thus it was removed.

Comment: Probably, no one used it because no one knew about it. I've honestly never tried to click the "votes cast" link. I had no idea until now that it pointed to the list of top voters...

Comment: @random: Well the `votes cast` link is a relatively new addition (compared to the rest of the dropdown).  If that page _was_ available since the addition but removed as you say, it sounds to me like it wasn't given much of a chance to begin with.

Comment: @random: I guess you're talking about something that was removed a long time (> 1 year) ago? Please keep in mind that nowadays it would be _very_ helpful for reviewing _question_ downvotes that are no longer visible in the reputation pages!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no overview of recently cast downvotes any more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91449/155585) (ping, @random)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, good point, now that we have a "votes tab" on the user profile it makes sense to point it there.

Comment: to be deployed ...