# How to follow up on my downvotes?

Tags: feature-request, support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There is no overview of recently cast downvotes any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91449/there-is-no-overview-of-recently-cast-downvotes-any-more)

When I downvote a question, I usually like to come back after a while to see if the question has been improved. Previously, when downvotes cost reputation I could access them from my reputation tab due to the penalty, but now that question downvotes are free they no longer show up there.

Is there any other way to easily find questions I've downvoted? If not, could something be added? I'd prefer not having to mark every question I downvote as a favorite.

Comment: +1 for asking a question which I was about to ask about a week ago.