# Show Downvote on Questions in Recent Activity

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There is no overview of recently cast downvotes any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91449/there-is-no-overview-of-recently-cast-downvotes-any-more)

Since removing the penalty for downvotes, the -1 does not show up in the recent activity drop down. Can this be added back in somehow? It is beneficial to see my recent activity.

Comment: Related request, it seems to basically ask for the same thing.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91449/there-is-no-overview-of-recently-cast-downvotes-any-more

Comment: You can "star" a post (mark it as favorite), if you want to come back to it later.

Comment: @Robert: Yes, but it isn't in the recent activity, right?