# How can I find where a removed downvote was?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, deleted-posts

I tend to [downvote mediocre answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/we-need-to-downvote-answers-more-even-mediocre-ones) a fair bit.

Sometimes these answers end up deleted.

My voting shows only existing answers, and not answers I've downvoted which were deleted.

Is there any way short of saving my downvotes somehow and scripting a check of existing downvotes vs removed ones to see where my "recovered" downvotes went?

It [sounds like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130383/193412) this is not possible currently (hence the feature request).

---

### EDIT: the linked "duplicate" question is only talking about including deleted DVed posts in your total votes.

I want to be able to see which posts I DVed were deleted. Nothing in the linked question addresses this. It is currently possible (through a roundabout way) to find this information and I am wanting to know if there is a better way (and/or suggesting this be possible).

---

### EDIT 2:

this is now showing up in my profile on The Workplace beta (I see a +1 whenever an answer I downvote is deleted) so I'm not sure if this is a new feature or not - I haven't received any new privileges there for quite some time so I'm not sure what caused this to happen.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your reputation history page, click the "show removed posts" checkbox. This will show reputation changes caused by post removal, which will have the title of the post. An example of this (a downvoted, deleted answer) is this:

[image]

Notice the "removed" title seems shorter than the "downvoted" title? They are the same post (same title), but the "removed" entry is not a link (and not bold text). If the deletion was within a day or two of your downvote, the link is easy to find (the entry corresponding to your vote). If the deletion happened much later, though, you've only got the title (unless you feel like digging all the way through your rep history).