# See the close reason I selected on close votes in my personal vote history

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, votes-tab

I can vote to close questions (I got enough reputation to do this). I can see my voting history (Votes > Closure in profile). However, I can't see **what** I voted to close questions as. Can we have this added in? Sometimes stuff isn't closed and I'm looking at my history and have *no idea* why I voted to close it whatsoever, and no way to tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow us to view the subcategories in the close dialog if already voted and what I voted for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259515/allow-us-to-view-the-subcategories-in-the-close-dialog-if-already-voted-and-what)

Comment: @Laurel this is about in the voting history page, not on questions.

Comment: @Laurel Not a duplicate. This is about the "votes" tab in one's user profile.

Comment: I second this suggestion. There are questions I cannot remember the close request I selected 5 minutes after selecting it :-(

Comment: Also note that this is possible on recommend closure flags, so it's an ability we lose on earning 3k rep.