# I can no longer see the close reason I chose

Tags: feature-request, bug, close-reasons, close-dialog

In the past, we used to know the exact close reason we chose when voting to close a question.

However, in the new close dialog, it's no longer possible:

> [image: close dialog without own reason]

In the above, I chose "A community-specific reason --> This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network". I have no way to confirm this after the vote was cast because one can not click on top entries (first page) on the dialog to visit the subentries (subsequent pages).

Can this ability be added back please?

Comment: IIRC you could see the top-level reason, but not the underlying one (for off-topic questions).

Comment: Screenshots of old dialogs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259515/282094

Comment: @Rob Technically that would make this question a duplicate of the one you linked to, correct?

Comment: @Mast No, this is even less information and a step back. Though that FR would be nice.

Comment: @Glorfindel only if a single vote was cast, then I can tell it's my own. It shows the total amount of votes cast. :(

Comment: @Mast, no. The question that I linked to is a Feature Request to **add an extra indicator** to show *which* of the multitude of prior votes displayed actually belongs to the account of the person opening the dialog; so they can see what they voted for prior to it closing, after closing **some** votes are available in their Review History while a few types are not shown. --- That question was commented on to support (confirm) this question by Shadow, otherwise there'd be at least a (1) next to the link `Close` above.

Comment: Please move or copy this to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/256282

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question Close Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/question-close-updates) - now that there's an official announcement, reports and feature-request​s belong there. Better not to have info scattered all over the place

Answer (score 10):

Note that hovering over the close link does tell you which reason you selected.

[image: screenshot showing the tooltip]

But I agree that the dialog should make it clear as well.

It would also be better if the terminology was consistent.

Comment: Great, but not much use on a touchscreen.

Comment: @PM2Ring Just hold the device really close to your face and it'll detect you hovering over it.

Comment: @TylerH great way to make your phone be infected with Corona. ;)

Comment: ha ha phones don't

Comment: That just says "Not suitable for this site". It doesn't say *which* community-specific close reason was chosen.